# Recommendation for python library / model / data-mining tool to find patterns in number sequence

Tags: python, sequence, data-mining

I have a long, cleaned (no duplicates in the order of appearance) sequence of integers in a pandas dataframe and I'm looking for a way to find patterns in it. The patterns i'm looking for could be described with the following parameters and possibly turn up like this:

```
example parameters:

A = constant increment of 10 
B = constant decrement of 6
C = constant decrement of 3
D = increment of 12 if no decrement larger than 5 within sequence-block

Sequence A-B-A 
Sequence D-B-A-C
```

Could someone give me a hint to find the right python tool to achieve this? Recommendations for Tools for automated search of unknown patterns in sequences would be also much appreciated. 
Thank you!

UPDATE:

This is the start of the sequence from where I print the constant increments in up and down order

```
seq  rt_up  rt_down
0      -      1
-1     1      -
0      2      -
1      3      -
2      -      1
1      -      2
0      -      3
-1     -      4
-2     -      5
-3     -      6
-4     -      7
-5     1      -
-4     2      -
-3     3      -
-2     4      -
-1     5      -
0      6      -
1      -      1
0      -      2
-1     1      -
0      -      1
-1     -      2
-2     -      3
-3     -      4
-4     -      5
-5     -      6
-6     1      -
-5     2      -
-4     3      -
-3     4      -
-2     5      -
-1     6      -
0      7      -
1      8      -
2      9      -
3      -      1
2      -      2
1      -      3
0      -      4
-1     -      5
```

I tried now to bin it with pd.cut:

```
bins = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8.......
```

So that i can label it like A (rt_up 6) = increment of 6, but I get an error saying:
bins must increase monotonically

I would need a solution to group it in a way that I can adjust the space between A and B in the original sequence, or just say if there's space count it as a sequence of A(rt_up x) and B (rt_down x ), or do not count it. 
 To clarify this: 
In the above sequence you see rt_up 1-6, then rt_down 1-2, then rt_up only 1 until it's follow by rt_down 1-6 again. The single 1 is the space

Comment: this sounds like a simple for loop to me, where you loop over the sequence of integers and then you yield the matching letter. Could you give an example for the sequence of integers for A-B-A and D-B-A-C?

Comment: @boraas please have a look on my update on the original question

Comment: All the information you need is stored in seq. If seq decreases, then you report the corresponding letter. Why do you need rt_up or rt_down?

Comment: I don't need rt_up or rt_down, it's there for illustration purpose only

Comment: I could make it that the corresponding letter gets reported if the sequence inc/dec, but I don't know how to do it that I get the letter A for seq length of 4, letter B for length of 5 , etc... I'm still a beginner with python / programming

Comment: what will be the output in letters for seq?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you mean with

> D=increment of 12 if no decrement larger than 5 within sequence-block

because I don't know what is a sequence-block.

```
seq=[0,-1,0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,-1]
inc=True
counter=0
prev=seq[0]
for item in seq[1:]:
  if prev < item and inc:
    counter=counter+1
  elif prev > item and not inc:
    counter=counter+1
  elif prev < item and not inc:
    # switch from increase to decrease
    # write out letters for increase
    if counter >= 10:
      print('A', end='')
    inc=False
    counter=0
  elif prev > item and inc:
    # switch from decrease to increase
    # write out letters for decrease
    if counter >= 6:
      print('B', end='')
    elif counter >= 3:
      print('C', end='')
    inc=True
    counter=0
print('')
```

For the example-sequence this would give:

`CC`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what `and inc` does. "If true" means that the condition block will always be executed? Furthermore `print('A', end='')` doesn't print any A's if I run it through the entire sequence, no matter which counter parameter has been set.

Comment: With "sequence block" I meant that there could be the simple block, like continuous inc/dec, and a more advanced block which allows inc/dec inbetween. example: block allows counter moves of 3 to be valid as a 10 increment seq(block): 1-2-3-4-5-6-5-4-3-4-5-6-7-8. this would be a 5-3-5 sequence, 10 increments in total from start to end. But I agree this makes things unnecessary complicated. I could use a normal 5-3-5 letter sequence

Comment: There is no constant increment of 10, therefore there is no "A"

Comment: In the original sequence, which is much longer, there are plenty of increments of 10, but the code's still not printing an A. However, I just found another solution. Instead of trying to search for a specific length/combination in the sequence, I readout the value of the length of all up/down blocks into a list. Later I can search the list for combinations. Thanks a lot for your help!